# AppleScript - Pressing "Connect" button automatically on a dialogue box in order to execute mount command

Tags: macos, applescript

I upgraded from Yosemite to Sierra and when I run my applescript code to mount my servers I get a dialogue box prompting me to "Cancel" or "Connect". I then press connect to continue.

[image]

I tried adding a keystroke return but I still get the dialogue box. What am I missing?

```
tell application "Finder"
    mount volume "smb://aeserver01"
    mount volume "smb://aeserver02"
    mount volume "smb://aeserver03"
    mount volume "smb://aeserver04"

    tell application "System Events" to keystroke return
end tell
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: congrats! you're the 15.000.000th question in stack overflow!

Comment: The `Finder` tell block is not needed. `mount volume` is part of Standard Additions.

Comment: Thank you vadian for your suggestion.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I cannot replicate the _dialog box_ shown in your question. I just tested under macOS 10.12.6, `mount volume "smb://$server/$share"` and it mounted without issue as my credentials for this are saved in my Keychain. Even without saved credentials, I cannot get the _dialog box_ in your question to show. I tested with both `mount volume "smb://$server"` and `mount volume "smb://$server/$share"` and both work as expected with or without saved credentials. If I cannot reproduce the shown behavior, there's not much more I can say, other then good luck solving your issue.

Comment: Thank you user3439894. I never had problems while on Yosemite but as soon as I connect on Sierra, I get that darn dialogue box. It doesn't prompt me when I try to connect via _afp_. Super strange...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

This may work for you, As it works for me on OS Sierra..

```
tell application "System Events"
    if exists of application process "NetAuthAgent" then
        tell application "NetAuthAgent" to activate
        delay 0.5
        try
            click UI element "Connect" of window 1 of application process "NetAuthAgent"
        end try
    end if
end tell
```

[image]

Comment: The dialog box shown in the OP doesn't come up of me, is there some setting that causes it to show?

Comment: Actually I'm not quite sure what causes that window to open.  I just happened to have, in my personal library of scripts, a script to “connect to server” which would input an IP address from my clipboard.  About every seventh or eighth run, that message window that the OP is struggling with, would pop up on my system.  I could not figure out the method to its madness on why and or when that message window would show up.  My solution was to add a “try” clause, as I posted in my answer, to handle that window whenever it did pop up

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @wch1zpink, but unfortunately it doesn't bypass that darn window. What I find weird is I came in this morning and all my servers mounted without any issue. After I unmount all the volumes and run the above code, the annoying popup comes back. Thanks again :-)